# Slurm: sbatch: fatal: Unable to process configuration file

Tags: slurm

I'm trying to use university's grid computing following this (probably old) guide http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/cmp/hardware/grid/
The problem is that I get this error

```
There was an error running the Slurm sbatch command.
The command was:
'/usr/bin/sbatch -e scr.sh.e%A -o scr.sh.o%A /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/scr.sh 2>&1'
and the output was:
'sbatch: error: Parsing error at unrecognized key: CPUd
 sbatch: error: Parse error in file /etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf line 189: " CPUd=24 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=6 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=198000 TmpDisk=360000 "
 sbatch: fatal: Unable to process configuration file
'
```

These are scr.sh I tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup /usr/local/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/repeats/cg.m > /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/outfile.txt 2> /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/error.txt &

#!/bin/sh -l
nohup /usr/local/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/repeats/cg.m > /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/outfile.txt 2> /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/error.txt &

#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/repeats/cg.m > /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/outfile.txt 2> /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/error.txt &

#!/bin/sh -l
/usr/local/bin/matlab -nodesktop -nodisplay < /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/repeats/cg.m > /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/outfile.txt 2> /datagrid/temporary/beliansky/repeats/error.txt &
```

I have never worked with anything like this before, so I'm a little bit lost here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously a typo in the global configuration file: the line in the error message

```
CPUd=24 Sockets=2 ...
```

should be

```
CPU=24 Sockets=2 ...
```

That is something only the administrators can fix.

What you can do is make a copy of that file, fix the typo, and then run

```
export SLURM_CONF=/path/to/your/copy
```

before running `sbatch`.